# Does an index take space in the disk?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am curious to know if an index in a database which is valid and used take up space in the disk or not.

Comment: On most database servers you can even see the index size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very vague, if you asked the question `does an Index take up "extra" space?`  Then the answer would be ......

No not in the case of a `Clustered Index`, a clustered index is the actual data stored in a sorted manner.

But on the other hand `Non-Clustered Index` is a separate structure to the actual table/data itself, containing pointers to the actual data, in this case Yes it would take up extra space .

Comment: M. Ali is right. One other thing -- If you're concerned with space or you're IO bound, you may want to take a look at compressing the index(es) and/or the cluster.

Comment: Well, even the *clustered index* needs to build up its tree structure above the actual data pages - so even the clustered index does take up some extra space

Comment: Can you kindly delete this answer. I am unable to delete the question because of that due to continuous downvotes.